# I want to get the list of dates in between these two dates and transfer no

Tags: php

$_SESSION['where']="(Trnsfr_Frm = '".$_SESSION["sysdept_id"]."') and (Trnsfer_Dt>=('%".$_POST["startdate"]."%') AND Trnsfer_Dt<=('%".$_POST["enddate"]."%')OR (Trnsfer_No like('%".$_POST["search"]."%')))  and Ord_Mstr_Id is null";

output
search by date or search by transfer no

i have two diffrent field for search one is globle search which is search the tranferno and one is local search for date wise search.

Comment: You're creating an advanced SQL injection with this approach. I'm not clear what your question is though, this is just a security note.

Comment: Hi Deepak. Welcome to SO. I recommend that you read SO's documentation on [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands your question is unclear and is unlikely to get a useful answer. Thanks.

Comment: it gives only search by date  while i want both either search by start date and end date or by transfer no .